# Environment variable always returns as undefined in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs

When I call `process.env.MAILHOST` which is in the `.env` it always returns `undefined` but if it's inside the project's src folder it returns the value that is informed

`D:\Projetos\login-jwt\login-jwt\configs\mailer.config.ts`

`console.log('mail',process.env.MAILHOST);`

return undefined

but on `D:\Projetos\login-jwt\login-jwt\src\main.ts`

`app.listen(process.env.PORT);`main.ts it finds the right value which is port 3000

**D:\Projetos\login-jwt\login-jwt.env.env**

```
PORT=3000
MAILHOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAILSERVICE=Gmail
MAILUSER=xxx@gmail.com
PASSWORD=xxx@pass
```

Comment: are you using some nestjs package to read & parse the `.env`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load environment variables from a folder root

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

your file should be named `.env` only in you project folder.